# Saving TiddlyWiki 5 to server using store.php

Tags: php, arrays, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

On the server, all in the same directory, and with all permissions set temporarily to 777 (including the directory itself):

- index.html (a copy of the [empty TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/empty.html))
- [store.php](https://code.google.com/p/bidix/source/browse/trunk/TiddlyHome/_th/lib/store.php)

I have edited the user list in store.php, and checked that the store.php page loads in the browser without errors.

```
$USERS = array(
    'myuser'=>'mypass', 
    'UserName2'=>'Password2', 
    'UserName3'=>'Password3');
```

And set the following in the Control Pannel "Saving" tab:

- Wiki Name: `myuser`
- Password: `mypass`
- Server URL: `http://myhostnoerrors/my_dir/store.php`
- Upload Directory: `.`
- Backup Directory: `.`

When I click the save button (or try to create a new Tiddler), I see the badge "Starting to save wiki" in the upper right, but the save icon stays red, and the file is not updated on my server (even if I refresh).

The "Network" Web Developer Tool in Firefox shows that the POST request is going to the right location and with the right information, but returns a 403 Forbidden error.

What am I doing wrong? Has anyone been able to use store.php successfully with version 5.1.7?

Comment: is your server showing a hit to the store.php URL?  EDIT: I see you edited in a mention of a 403 -- I guess you're getting that from the server.  Might still be worth confirming it's apache / nginx / whatever returning the 403 and not some security thing.

Comment: @DanielBaird: I get a hit in my error log when I try to save: `Multipart parsing error (init): Multipart: Invalid boundary in C-T (malformed)`. Simultaneously I get a hit in my access log showing the 403 error for the POST request.

Comment: @DanielBaird: the response header is from Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.7 mod_auth_pgsql/2.0.3

Comment: Have you tried `./` as the upload directory, not simply `.`?

Comment: Can you grab the POST using a browser plugin or something, and check if there's a charset attribute?  Other people getting that error (not with UploadPlugin, just generally with other PHP tools) say that having a charset specified in a multipart form submission can trigger that "malformed" error.

Comment: I had a similar error. Since I was using `https` my mistake was issuing a `Server URL` with `http` instead of `https`. Now it woks fine.

Comment: Could you please update the link to store.php if there's a new repo and you're aware of it? https://code.google.com/archive/p/bidix/source looks empty to me

Answer (score 1):

Had similar problem on my raspberry pi with an archlinux on it. Solution was to enable apache "`Overwrite`" setting and replace deprecated "split" by "`preg_split`"  implementation in store.php script.

Comment: Replacing `split` with `preg_split` is what solved the issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir($structure, 0777, true)
```

In Your `mkdirs($dir)` function You are creating directory recursive .
So You have to give permission for the directory.
The default Mode is 0777 but it will ignored on Windows.
So Give permission for all folder.

Comment: I created the directories manually using an FTP client, and set the permissions for the directory as well. I don't think it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Try with terminal Using 'SSH' .FTP will create folder and set permission.But some time system does not support it. So try with terminal .